# Increment value in Firebase Realtime Database for Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I want to increment an int:

```
_refUsers.Child(U.clickedby).Child("score").SetValueAsync(+=1);
```

It seems the ServerValue.increment() operation is not available for Unity.

What is a good way to do it in Unity?

Comment: You could also simply do `GetValueAsync` -> when done -> +1 -> `SetValueAsync`

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there is something like ServerValue.increment for Unity.

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention it, so it seems to not have been ported (yet): https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/server-value